# Geometry and induction Discrete Math

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, induction, coloring

Claim: Suppose that we draw any number of straight lines in the plane, with the restriction that no
two are parallel and no intersection point belongs to more than two lines. The lines divide up the plane
into a set of regions. We're going to color each region red or green. It is possible to choose the color
for each region so that adjacent regions never have the same color.
In this claim, \adjacent" means that the two regions share an edge. Two regions touching at a single
point are not considered adjacent. Also remember that a \line" (as opposed to a \line segment") goes
o to innity at both ends. So each line cuts the plane into two pieces.
Use induction to prove this claim.

I was just wondering if anyone could help me start off this question?

Comment: Start with the base case where you have 1 line splitting the plane into two regions: one red and one green.

For the inductive hypothesis, assume that the claim holds true for N total non-parallel, non-intersecting lines. Then, what happens when you add one more line to this configuration? Does the claim still hold true? Why?

Comment: if you add one more line then you split the two regions even more?

Comment: @Bob, what's to be gained from giving this away?